# Url Rewrite for year, month and day

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I want to achieve something like this: http://example.com/year/month/day instead of http://example.com?year=yyyy&month=mm&day=dd

I want it to rewrite only when the matches are numbers only, when the first segment (year) is a 4 digit no, the 2nd segment month is between 01 and 12 (months of d year), the last segment (day) is between 01 - 31 (days in a month).

Please how can i achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you *should* check month and day number in your script. But here is regexp.

Updated to match single digit day or month with optional trailing slash.

```
RewriteRule ^(\d{4})/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/?$ ?y=$1&m=$2&d=$3
```

For year and month only with optional trailing slash.

```
RewriteRule ^(\d{4})/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/?$ ?y=$1&m=$2
```

Comment: You *should* check month and day number in your script.

Comment: @Teneff No, as after last two digits must be `EOL`.

Comment: It's working great, just you may have to consider about an optional forward slash at the end :)

Comment: thanks so much, i noticed that if 01 is written as 1, it doesnt work, pls how can i fix it; in addition, if i want to work with year and month only, do i remove '((?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]))/'?

Comment: @Ogugua Belonwu: Updated answer.

Comment: Here's a variation of the above, but with month and day optional:
`RewriteRule ^(\d{4})/?((1[0-2]|0?[1-9])/?((0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/?)?)?$ dueby.php?y=$1&m=$3&d=$5 [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 2):

the best I can think of is this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\d{4})/(0[1-9]|10|11|12)/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/?$  index.php?y=$1&m=$2&d=$3 [L]
```

Comment: thanks so much, i noticed that if 01 is written as 1, it doesnt work, pls how can i fix it; in addition, if i want to work with year and month only, do i remove '(0[1-9]|10|11|12)/'?